# Solving trigonometric equation for $a$ and $b$

Tags: trigonometry

Does anybody know of a quick way of finding real $a$ and $b$ for the equation $2\sin  (x+10)= a\sin x + b\cos x$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you know the trigonometric identity
$$\sin(x+y)=\cos(x) \sin(y)+\sin(x)\cos(y)$$
So $$2\sin(x+10)=2 \cos(10)\sin(x)+2 \sin(10)\cos(x)$$ 
Now you can choose $$a=\frac{1}{2\cdot \cos(10)}$$ 
and $$b=\frac{1}{2 \sin(10)}$$

Comment: I was just working it out and I had put 10 in y's spot, just wondering why it is the other way around.

Comment: how do you mean "the other way around"  ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I must be overtired, thank you for your help.

Comment: na english is a foreign language, i really want to help if you still have a question :)

Comment: No, really its perfect, just switched the cos an sin in the equation.